# Getting TypeError while accessing function through $refs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using $refs to call function. it is working fine . but for some team member it is not working although we have same version for every dependency. do not know why this issue produce.

```
<component-table ref="table" :col="col" :enable-select="true" :multiSelect="true" data="data"></component-table>
```

getting error while performing deselect

```
this.$refs.table.deselectAll()  // getting error for some people
                               // TypeError occured
                              // this.$refs.table.deselectAll is not a function
```

on console of table refs

```
console.log(this.$refs.table)     // below is output structure

VueComponent
    $refs
        dataTable :VueComponent
            deselectAll: f()
                arguments: [TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be 
                            accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls 
                            to them
                            at Function.r (<anonymous>:1:83)]
                caller: [TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be 
                            accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls 
                            to them
                            at Function.r (<anonymous>:1:83)]
                length: 0
                name: "bound deselectAll"
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem . It's unknown when the method is called, how the component is used, what's the context for console output - does it come from "some team member"?

Comment: yes , it is from one of team member